# Python Web Scraping Not Working -- Multiple Pages Project

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to webscraping and have been working on a project to scrape data from a jobbank site. I wanted to know why my code isn't working. When running as a single site, it works just fine, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in regards to multiple pages.

## import libraries

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import datetime
```

## Connect to Website and pull data

```
#for page in range(37001458,37001470):
pages = np.arange (37001458, 37001470, 1)
data = []

for page in pages:
    
    URL = 'https://www.jobbank.gc.ca/jobsearch/jobposting/' + str(page)
    sleep(randint(1,5))
    
# To find Your User-Agent: https://httpbin.org/get
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}


#for single page scraping - delete everything before this line except headers and readdress response
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")

#page = page + 1

try:
      job_title = soup2.find(property='title').get_text()
except:
      job_title = ''

try:
    date_posted = soup2.find(property='datePosted').get_text()
except:
    date_posted = ''

try:
    company = soup2.find(property='hiringOrganization').get_text()
except:
    company = ''

try:
    address = soup2.find(property='streetAddress').get_text()
except:
    address = ''

try:
    city = soup2.find(property='addressLocality').get_text()
except:
    city = ''

try:
    province = soup2.find(property='addressRegion').get_text()
except:
    province = ''

try:
    wage = soup2.find(property='minValue').get_text()
except:
    wage = ''

try:
    wage_reference = soup2.find(property='unitText').get_text()
except:
    wage_reference = ''

try:
    work_hours = soup2.find(property='workHours').get_text()
except:
    work_hours = ''

try:
    employment_type = soup2.find(property='employmentType').get_text()
except:
    employment_type = ''

try:
    language = soup2.find(property='qualification').get_text()
except:
    language = ''

try:
    required_education = soup2.find(property='educationRequirements qualification').get_text()
except:
    required_education = ''

try:
    required_experience = soup2.find(property='experienceRequirements qualification').get_text()
except:
    required_experience = ''

try:
    skills = soup2.find(property='experienceRequirements').get_text()
except:
    skills = ''

try:
    employment_groups = soup2.find(id='employmentGroup').get_text()
except:
    employment_groups = ''
```

## Data Cleaning

```
job_title = job_title.strip()

date_posted = date_posted.strip()[10:]

company = company.strip()

address = address.strip()

city = city.strip()

province = province.strip()

wage = wage.strip()

wage_reference = wage_reference.strip()

work_hours = work_hours.strip()

employment_type = employment_type.strip()

language = language.strip()

required_education = required_education.strip()

required_experience = required_experience.strip()

skills = skills.strip()

employment_groups = employment_groups.strip()[238:] 

print(job_title)
print(date_posted)
print(company)
print(address)
print(city)
print(province)
print(wage)
print(wage_reference)
print(work_hours)
print(employment_type)
print(language)
print(required_education)
print(required_experience)
print(skills)
print(employment_groups)
```

## Timestamp for output to track when data was collected

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

print(today)
```

## Data Entry into csv file (prior creation)

```
import csv

header = ['Job Title', 'Date Posted', 'Company', 'Address', 'City', 'Province', 'Wage', 'Wage Reference', 'Work Hours', 'Employment Type', 'Language', 'Required Education', 'Required Experience', 'Skills', 'Employment Groups']
values = [job_title, date_posted, company, address, city, province, wage, wage_reference, work_hours, employment_type, language, required_education, required_experience, skills, employment_groups]


with open('CanadaJobBankWebScraperDataset.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(values)
```

## Pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\AM\CanadaJobBankWebScraperDataset.csv')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pages = np.arange (37001458, 37001470, 1)

for page in pages:
    
    URL = 'https://www.jobbank.gc.ca/jobsearch/jobposting/' + str(page)
    sleep(randint(1,5))

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

This loop creates a url string, and then immediately recreates it with a different number on the end, and then does it again, and again, and again.  Only the final url value actually survives when the loop ends.

The `requests.get()` call (and all the related processing) needs to be *inside* the for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! Life saver, I had to make some modifications to the csv writer too at the end, it's working now!